# Octave beginner help. Creating a function that takes a component matrix as a parameter and returns a matrix?

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, octave

I need to create a function that takes a component matrix as a parameter and returns a matrix?

Apparently this function should normalise my data?
There are other instructions along with this step in my project such as:
Take the matrix and calculate the mean value along a certain column. 
Calculate the difference between the measurement and this mean.
Subtract this difference from each measurement.
Return corrected matrix to the script.
Place corrected matrix in a variable within the script.

(I don't know if this is what the function is supposed to do or anything I'm completely lost and any help would be appreciated thanks!)

Comment: So you know: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How did you end up in the situation you describe? (*"I don't know if this is what the function is supposed to do or anything I'm completely lost and any help would be appreciated thanks!"*)

Answer (score 2):

This is probably homework but I'll help you get started.

To create a function which takes a matrix and return a matrix:

```
function m_out = my_function(m_in)
    %insert calculations here
end
```

To find the 2-norm of a matrix (which is the largest singular value):

```
the_norm = norm(my_matrix); % returns a scalar, 2-norm of matrix
```

To find the mean of a vector:

```
the_mean = mean(my_vector); % returns a scalar, mean of the vector
```

To access a specific column of a matrix:

```
my_col = my_matrix(:, col_number); % my_col is a vector
```

To access a specific row of a matrix:

```
my_row = my_matrix(row_num, :); % my_row is a vector
```

To subtract a scalar (single number) from a matrix:

```
new_matrix = old_matrix - single_number; % returns a matrix
```

To store a matrix into a variable (example):

```
my_matrix = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
```

Give it a try creating a function which puts this all together.

Comment: +1 for all the suggestions without actually doing the homework of the OP.